# What's the difference between “bucket” and “pail”?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns, vocabulary, transatlantic-differences

What is the difference between *bucket* and *pail*?

- Is there a distinction between the shape of a bucket and the shape of a pail?
- Are buckets and pails made of different materials?
- Is there a difference between substances carried in buckets and pails?
- Is there dialectal variation in the use of these words?
- Is one of these words old-fashioned?

In other words,

- When is a native English speaker more likely to use the word *bucket*? (Please state the whereabouts of the speaker in question)
- When is a native English speaker more likely to use the word *pail*? (Ditto)

Comment: "You don't look like a well bucket."   "No, I'm a little pail."

Comment: @Vitaly I’ve greatly expanded my answer for you; hope this helps!

Comment: Answer: depends on your dialect, esp. in American English. See DARE http://dare.wisc.edu/ and some discussion http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4141

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel like the word *pail* almost always describes a metallic object, shaped in a near-cylindrical fashion. Sometimes a pail can be wooden, but rarely. *Buckets* can be made of any old material, especially plastic, and can be shaped more strangely than pails.

---

In addition, *bucket* has some interesting and amusing uses in slang:

1. In its plural form, it can be an expression of unalloyed happiness. It comes from the slang term from having just scored a field goal in basketball.  For example, if you had just won something unexpected in the mail, you might say "*Buckets!*" to celebrate it, just as you might having scored playing basketball.
   [image]
2. It can describe a particularly decrepit vehicle, a *hoop-ti*; most often applied to vans. [image]
3. It's an urban slang term for urban-style hats, typically wide-brim and loose fitting.
   [image: Bucket hats]
4. It's an urban slang term for expensive rims on a car.  As so memorably used by the rapper Yung Joc,
   "*...ride around slow so you can see the buckets on my feet [tires]...*"
   [image]

*Pail*, sad to say, is utterly lacking in this regard.

**EDIT**: Taking a look through Google's N-Gram viewer, it's not hard to see why:

[image: Chart comparing 'bucket' and 'pail' in Google's N-Gram viewe]

This comparison of *bucket* and *pail* from 1800 till today shows the latter's usage diverging noticeably from the former's around the era of 1940–1960, to becoming a much less popular a synonym for the former nowadays.  The chart makes a lot of sense to me, at least superficially; the 1950s–1960s was an era where college attendance and job mobility were first greatly expanded and democratized, and where a lot of young adults who might have grown up to  work on the family farm in older times instead found white-collar, professional work.  As *pail* in literature is strongly associated in my mind with farming contexts, it makes sense to me that authors would have limited their use of *pail* in that era given its more limited relevance towards their target audience. If a word doesn't quite have a "regular" currency, obviously there will be fewer opportunities for it to make its way into slang usage.

Comment: Of course this analysis assumes that "bucket" and "pail" are totally synonymous in literature...this assumption seems a pretty fair one to me, given how other the answers given here argue the same thing.

Comment: Case #1 must be a geographically localized colloquialism, as I've never heard it.  Case #2 is a shortening of "bucket of bolts".

Comment: This is mostly wrong, a bucket or a pail can be made of any material and what they are made of has nothing to do with it.  Both  stem from Middle English roots, and they mean the exact same thing.  In common usage they mean exactly the same thing.  They are generally used regionally in different areas of the united states, and have nothing to do with social status or anything else.  Please see the dictionary and the eymology of the word.  Only the slang citations are accurate.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Perhaps "bucket of bolts" is American-only - I don't think I've never heard it in the UK. We often call a car like that a [rust bucket](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it's+a+rust-bucket%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - an expression which was also generically applied to certain models where poor design/inferior materials meant *every* example was liable to corrode prematurely. Largely a thing of the past with most more recent models.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: We're familiar with the phrase "rust bucket" also.  "Bucket of bolts" refers more to care in manufacturing than quality of materials, when fasteners might not have been sufficiently tightened (or even installed at all), resulting in loose bolts rolling around inside the "bucket".  Of course, either condition can develop over time.

Comment: What about *buckets* that roughly means pigeonholes? Like the buckets inside a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) I've never heard of these having "pails" but instead "buckets".

Answer (score 11):

They are synonyms, but not completely interchangeable. *Bucket* has a more extensive set of meanings, and can be used to describe

- the scoop of a dredger or grain elevator
- the scoop attached to the front of a loader, digger or tractor
- a unit of data that can be transferred from a backing store in a single operation (computing)
- *slang* the scoring of a goal in basketball
- an old boat that's in poor shape

[NOAD]

Comment: +1 for the right answer, since the accepted answer and the other answer with more votes are both wrong.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** This answer has three main sections: the first answers each of the original subquestions one by one, the second is the OED entry for *pail*, and the third is a selection of citations from literature.

---

The original poster asked the following questions:

> - What is the difference between bucket and pail?

Sometimes nothing, but sometimes a great deal.  There are cases where the two words can be freely interchanged, but many others where they cannot.  When there is a difference, bucket is the hypernym of pail, in that pail is a more specific sort of thing and bucket is more generic.

Pail takes on many attributes of can or cannister, including the property of holding liquids. A *pail* is a specific sort of shipping container. A bucket is sometimes closer to a basket or tub.  As no one would ever think to interchange basket and pail, this shows part of where the distinction  between the two necessarily lies.

This leads to a good **rule of thumb**: If you could use *can* or *cannister* instead of *pail*, then you probably should not use *bucket*.  If you could use *basket* or *tub* instead of *bucket*, you probably should not use *pail*.

Consider what happens when you go to an old-fashioned well to fetch water from it. There is a bucket permanently attached to the well, which you use to retrieve water from the bottom of the well.  However, the thing you pour that water into to bring back with you would usually be a pail.  That is, you use pails to fetch water from the bucket in the well.  If you brought a bucket with you to get that water, it would be assumed to be larger than if you brought a pail.

> - Is there a distinction between the shape of a bucket and the shape of a pail?

Both are modified cylinders, but like a can, a pail is more apt to have sides perpendicular to its bottom than is a bucket, whereas a bucket like a basket or tub often has a wider top than bottom. Pails are also more apt to have a handle on them, although garbage pails and some of the shipping cannisters referred to as pails do not.  But watering pails have handles and a spout for pouring.  A bucket might have a handle, but it wouldn’t have a spout.

> - Are buckets and pails made of different materials?

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  Because a pail is generally used to hold liquids, some materials and structures are forbidden in a pail or can that are allowed in a bucket or basket. You cannot have a chain or mesh or wire or fishnet or wicker pail, because the liquid would just flow out through the holes.  But you can have a chain or wire-frame basket perfectly well.  Consider the piece of hardware used in basketball to score “a bucket”, the one made of netting. That could not be called  a pail due to the netting.

> - Is there a difference between substances carried in buckets and pails?

Sometimes. Pails like cans are good for carrying liquids. Also, a very large basket can even carry people in it, which you would never use the word pail for.

> - Is there dialectal variation in the use of these words?

Apparently so; according to the OED entry cite below, *“The precise range of vessels denoted by pail, **as distinct from the near-synonymous** bucket, has varied over time, and **there continues to be much regional variation.** ”*

> - Is one of these words old-fashioned?

Certainly not in General American, no. I have some specific citations below.

For example, where garbage pail is commonplace, garbage bucket is almost completey unknown.  Some people use watering can and others watering pails, but a watering bucket is much harder to come by, and probably means something else in that context. Similarly, a pail of milk is much more frequent than a bucket of milk, which seems like it would be large and heavy, and unsuitable for pouring.

> - When is a native English speaker more likely to use the word bucket? (Please state the whereabouts of the speaker in question)
> - When is a native English speaker more likely to use the word pail? (Ditto)

I’m from rural Wisconsin, part of the Inland North. For the record, I’m from an area that lacks the *cot–caught* merge, distinguishes a (ceramic) *bubbler* from a(n electric) *water fountain*, and sometimes opposes *home-made* with *store-bought**en***. Oh, and we have a lot of cows. :)

There are many places I could not swap pail and bucket. I’ve tried to list some of them above, and why. Remember also that you never ship things in buckets, only in pails. I have other published differences below. For me, a pail and a bucket are similar, but there are many places where you must use one and must not use the other, which proves they are not identical.  Here are some of them:

- Garbage goes in a garbage **pail**; you cannot say bucket there, although you may say garbage can.
- Milk goes in a **pail**; you cannot say bucket there.
- To score, a basketball goes in its **bucket**; you cannot say pail there.
- Jack and Jill fetched a **pail** of water; you cannot say bucket there unless perhaps they both were carrying the same one because it is larger. Note,  though, there was a bucket at the well.
- A child at the beach carries water in a colorful little plastic **pail**; you could not call that a bucket.
- One can only have a watering can or watering **pail**, never a watering *bucket.

Here is [an ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=garbage+pail%2C+garbage+bucket%2C+pail+of+milk%2C+bucket+of+milk&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showing how much more common pail is than bucket in a couple of typical usages:

[image: ngram of garbage pail and bucket, pail or bucket of milk]

And here’s another contextual distinction:
[image]

And here’s one more.  I don’t know what happened with lunch pails in 1958. I also don’t know how to get ngrams to talk about “lunch-pail” with a hyphen, a form cited by the OED entry immediately below.

[image]

## OED Entry

The OED points out that pails generally have handles and are especially suited for carrying liquids. It calls pails near-synonyms to buckets, but not identical. It points out there is regional variation.

I’ve omitted the Forms and the Compounds sections below.

> **Etymology**:  < Anglo-Norman *paele, paelle, paiele, paile, paiel, pale* pan, bucket and Old French, Middle French *paele, paelle, paielle, payelle* frying pan (c1150), warming pan, brazier, cauldron (c1170), salt pan (mid 13th cent. in the source translated in quot. 1481 at sense 2), liquid measure (c1275; Middle French *poile*, French *poêle*) < classical Latin *patella*   small pan or dish, plate, in post-classical Latin also salt pan (8th cent.): see **patella** *n.*   Compare post-classical Latin *paella* (from late 12th cent. in British sources; also as *paila*, *payla*).
>
> Old English *pægel*   wine vessel, liquid measure (see quot. below) is unrelated (compare West Frisian *pegel*   liquid measure, quarter of a litre, Middle Dutch *pēgel, peile*   liquid measure, water level marker (Dutch *peil*   water level marker, Dutch regional *pegel*   icicle), Middle Low German *pēgel*   liquid measure, water level marker, German *Pegel*   water level marker, water level, German regional (Swiss) *beile*   measuring stick, Danish *pægl*   (now *hist*.) liquid measure, half a pint, all probably ultimately < post-classical Latin *pagella*   unit of measurement (9th cent.), spec. use of classical Latin *pāgella*   small page, column of writing < the same base as *pāgina*  **page** *n.²*   + -*ella*  -**ella** *suffix*); compare:
>
> OE   *Antwerp Gloss.* (1955) 85   *Gillo*, pægel.
>
> It is unclear whether examples such as the following are to be interpreted as showing the Middle English or the Anglo-Norman word:
>
> - 1336–7   in F. R. Chapman *Sacrist Rolls Ely* (1907) II. 80   In j payle pro cibo conservand.
> - 1352–3   in F. R. Chapman *Sacrist Rolls Ely* (1907) II. 155   Item in ij payles, j boket, de nouo empt. pro ecclesia.
> - 1393   in L. T. Smith *Exped. Prussia & Holy Land Earl Derby* (1894) 174   Pro ij payles ligneis, ij s. pr.
> - 1423   *Rolls of Parl.* IV. 241   Item, xxxi Pottez du Bras‥Item, xix Pailles de Bras‥Item, xxvii Pailles de Bras rumpuz‥Item, xii Pailles ovec longe handels, pris le pec' viii d.

> 1. a. An open-topped vessel with a hooped carrying handle, typically of slightly tapering cylindrical shape, used esp. for holding or carrying liquids; (now more generally) a bucket. In early use also: †a container for food, a kitchen vessel (*obs*.).
>      <sup><sub>The precise range of vessels denoted by pail, as distinct from the near-synonymous bucket, has varied over time, and there continues to be much regional variation. As a word for a container for milk *pail* has long been preferred (cf. *milk-pail* *n.* at **milk** *n.¹* and *adj*. Compounds 1b), and it is now frequently taken to be a container for liquids, esp. one made of metal (or plastic); though originally it was made of wooden staves hooped with iron. Cf. *dinner-pail* *n.* at **dinner** *n.* Compounds 2, *lunch-pail* *n.* at **lunch** *n.²* Compounds 1. Recorded earliest in *pail-hoop* *n.* at Compounds 1.</sub></sup>
>
>    - 1341–2   in F. R. Chapman *Sacrist Rolls Ely* (1907) II. 117,   ij paylhopes pro Cementariis, j d.
>    - *a*1425   in T. Wright & R. P. Wülcker *Anglo-Saxon & Old Eng. Vocab.* (1884) I. 666   *Hec multra,* payle.
>    - *c*1487   J. Skelton tr. Diodorus Siculus *Bibliotheca Historica* ɪᴠ. 253   The capitaigne purveyeth for moch cataile vnto his paile, and so myngeth to-gedre mylk and blode.
>    - 1530   J. Palsgrave *Lesclarcissement* 250/2   Payle a vessell, *seau*.
>    - 1577   B. Googe tr. C. Heresbach *Foure Bks. Husbandry* ɪɪ. f. 66,   The Gardners in the end of Sommer, doo take the rootes, and set them in pannes, pottes, or payles.
>    - *a*1639   H. Wotton *Reliquiæ Wottonianæ* (1651) 524   Jone takes her neat-rub'd paile, and now She trips to milk the Sand-red cow.
>    - 1697   Dryden tr. Virgil *Pastorals* ɪɪ, in tr. Virgil *Wks*. 7   New Milk that‥overflows the Pails.
>    - 1727   ‘S. Brunt’ *Voy. to Cacklogallinia* 34   They carried two Pails a-piece with a Yoke, like our Tub-women.
>    - 1798   R. Southey *Well of St. Keyne* v,   There came a man from the house hard by At the Well to fill his pail.
>    - 1846   E. W. Farnham *Life in Prairie Land* 129   The best ewer I could get was an old pail.
>    - 1897   H. Wing *Milk & its Products* v. 81   All vessels used to contain milk should be heavily tinned; pails, cans, and the like, that are of the kind called ironclad are preferable on account of durability.
>    - 1965   A. Lurie *Nowhere City* i. 9   He‥took the mop out of the tin pail by the back door, and crammed the flowers into the pail.
>    - 1997   *Sierra* Nov.–Dec. 62/2   The kids have collected a menagerie of water critters in a pail by dragging long-handled dip nets through the turbid, shallow water.
>
> b. A pail and its contents; an amount such as would fill a pail; a pailful (usually of liquid).
>
> - 1592   B. Rich *Aduentures of Brvsanvs* ɪɪ. viii. 69   Like a madde man that would power on a paile of water when he ment to make the fire burne.
> - *a*1616   Shakespeare *Comedy of Errors* (1623) v. i. 174   Euer as it blaz'd, they threw on him Great pailes of puddled myre to quench the haire.
> - 1647   in F. Roberts & I. M. M. Macphail *Dumbarton Common Good Accts.* (1972) 156   Givin for thrie payules wyne with tobacco and pypes.
> - 1700   *Moxon's Mech. Exercises: Bricklayers-wks.* 21   They may throw Pales of Water on the Wall after the Bricks are lay'd.
> - 1779   G. Keate *Sketches from Nature* (ed. 2) I. 42   But why do we stop?‥ Only to give the horses a pail of water, replies the postillion.
> - 1840   R. H. Dana *Two Years before Mast* vii. 55   A small boat‥brought, as a present to the crew, a large pail of milk, a few shells, and a block of sandal wood.
> - 1886   T. H. Hall Caine *Son of Hagar* ɪ. v,   Crossing the garden with a pail of water just raised from the well.
> - 1914   S. Lewis *Our Mr. Wrenn* ii. 20   If you was in heaven and there was a pail of beer on one side and a gold harp on the other‥and you was to have your pick, which would you take?
> - 1953   J. Baldwin *Go tell it on Mountain* ɪɪ. ii. 170   He put the two pails of water carefully on the ground.
> - 1993   *Outdoor Canada* Oct. 52/3   She trudged through the marshy areas picking pails of Cloudberries.
>
> c. Used *allusively* in various phrases with reference to milking.
>
> - 1615   G. Markham *Eng. Hus-wife* in *Countrey Contentments* 104   When age‥shall disable her [*sc*. a cow] for the payle,‥she may be‥made fit for the shambles.
> - 1652   *Observ. upon Aristotles Politiques* 34   Excise is paid by all retailers of Wine, and other commodities; for each Tun of Beer six shillings, for each Cow for the Paile two Stivers every week.
> - 1758   R. Brown *Compl. Farmer* (1759) 19   The best sort of cows for the pail.
> - 1812   W. P. Newby *Let*. in J. J. Looney *Papers T. Jefferson* (Retirement Series) (2008) V. 260   By endeavouring to brake one of my young cows to the pail we have lost her.
>     1888   F. T. Elworthy *W. Somerset Word-bk.* (at cited word),   A cow is said to be ‘a come'd in to pail’ when her calf is gone, and all her milk becomes available for the dairy.
>     1888   T. Hardy *Withered Arm* in *Blackwood's Edinb. Mag.* Jan. 30/1   The cows were ‘in full pail’.
>     1956   D. E. Marshall *Eng. People 18th Cent.* vi. 205   With better agriculture and more fodder crops came a greater concentration on the breeding of livestock. Hitherto, sheep, valued as mobile dung-carts, had been bred for their fleeces, and cattle for the pail and the plough.
>
> †2. A shallow pan, *esp*. one used to obtain salt by the evaporation of brine; a salt pan. *Obs*.
>
> - 1481   *Myrrour of Worlde* (Caxton) ɪɪ. xxi. 112   Nygh vnto metz the cyte is a water that renneth there, the whiche is soden in grete payelles [Fr. *paales*] of copper, and it becometh salt fayr and good.
> - 1494   *Loutfut MS* f. 24<sup>v</sup>, in *Dict. Older Sc. Tongue* at (*Paill*),   Be the sownd of paelles tymbres & othir thingis that makis gret noyes.

**Citation**

> pail, n.1
>   Third edition, March 2005; online version March 2012. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/136047; accessed 04 May 2012. An entry for this word was first included in New English Dictionary, 1904.

### Examples

As one coherent set of examples showing *bucket* versus *pail*, George R.R. Martin is a contemporary American author and editor of fantasy and fiction, popular for his *Song of Ice and Fire* world which HBO has been adapting for its popular TV show, *Game of Thrones*.

Over the course of the five books published so far, he uses pail 57 times and bucket 62 times, including sentences in which both notably occur as distinct, ***contrasting*** (!) items: “Rich men had it piped into their homes; the poor filled **their pails and buckets** at public fountains.”

Martin also has people using pails to carry water back from the bucket at an old-fashioned well, which again shows these two are different in his usage. Finally, he employs a very large bucket to haul people up a sheer mountainside.

Here’s a sampling of illustrative sentence, in order of occurrence, from Martin’s five published novels in the series, with NPs in which *pale* or *bucket* appears emboldened below. I feel that the range of these citations gives a good feel for how and when pails and buckets are considered distinct.

- On his head was a mock helm fashioned from **an old tin bucket**, with a rack of deer antlers strapped to the crown and hung with cowbells.
- One afternoon, while she was waiting her turn to draw **a pail of water** from the well, she heard the hinges of the east gate groaning.
- Squires tossed **pails of water** over cookfires, while soldiers took out their oilstones to give their blades one last good lick.
- The lamplight revealed **a pail overflowing with feces** in one corner and a huddled shape in another.
- She kicked over **the waste pail**.
- She was thinking about the coin as she crossed the Flowstone Yard, struggling with the weight of the water in **her pail**.
- **Half a hundred buckets of seawater** still hung from the gunwales, in case of fires.
- Tyrion had seen her only yesterday, climbing the serpentine steps with **a pail of water**.
- Davos would talk to the gaolers whenever they came to his cell, whether to bring him food or change **his slops pail.** [. . .]  “The pail,” said Davos, gesturing. [. . .]  His lordship stared at the pail in horror.
- Jarl told them to be quick about it, before he had to throw **a pail of water** over them.
- Women were filling **pails** and flagons there.
- The wildlings might have a hundred and twenty men, but four defenders would be enough to see them off, with a few well-placed arrows and perhaps **a pail of stones.**
- “I am tired of having highborn women kicking **pails of shit** at me, Father.
- She used the dog’s head as  **a pail**.
- Dodging from its path, he just avoided being spattered as a townswoman emptied **a pail of night soil** from a window overhead.
- He put her on the second floor, and a woman with a liver-colored birthmark on her face brought up a wooden tub, and then the water, **pail by pail**.
- Rich men had it piped into their homes; the poor filled **their pails and buckets** at public fountains.
- They had **pails of soap and water**, and were scrubbing at the floor.
- And **a nice new pail for me to shit in**, I don’t doubt.
- Qyburn dropped the bloody razor into **a pail of vinegar**.
- Lothor Brune was in the winch room, helping the gaoler Mord and two serving men wrestle chests of clothes and bales of cloth into **six huge oaken buckets**, each big enough around to hold three men.
- The chain uncoiled, rattling as it scraped across the stone, **the oaken bucket** swaying as it began its long descent to Sky.
- Some of the winch chains were fixed to wicker baskets, others to **stout oaken buckets**.
- When Robert climbed gingerly from **the bucket**, she knelt in a patch of snow to kiss his hand and cheeks.
- Jon had given his chief captive the largest cell, **a pail to shit in**, enough furs to keep him from freezing, and a skin of wine.
- Then it seemed to take forever to come to a rolling boil and twice forever to fill **six wooden pails**.
- “Another bloody bath?” said their serjeant when he saw **the pails of steaming water**.
- **Two pails** for Penny, two for Tyrion, and four for Ser Jorah, two in either hand. [. . .]  He dropped **the bucket** down the well once more.
- They started back, each of the dwarfs carrying **two brim-full pails of sweet water** and Ser Jorah with two pails in each hand.
- Water sloshed from **his pails** with every stride, splashing round his legs, whilst his bells played a marching song.
- Tyrion set **the pails of water** on the ground, grateful for the halt.
- More refuse showered down from windows and balconies: half-rotted fruit, **pails of beer**, eggs that exploded into sulfurous stink when they cracked open on the ground.
- At the Green Fork, he had fought in mismatched scraps of plate from Lord Lefford’s wagons, with a spiked bucket helm that made it look as if someone had upended **a slops pail** over his head.

Comment: Please note that in your own citation, the word BUCKET is used to define the word PAIL, indication that they have the same meaning.  If one word is used to define another word, they can be said to mean the same thing. -1 because this question was already answered correctly by someone else before your answer. "a. An open-topped vessel with a hooped carrying handle, typically of slightly tapering cylindrical shape, used esp. for holding or carrying liquids; (now more generally) **a bucket**. "

Comment: Yes, I do put milk in a bucket.  I do because they are the same thing, and, in my area of the country we never say Pail.  Even in your citation, in the OED, "pail" is defined, and I quote,un-qualified by any other verbiage, **a bucket**.  That means that they have the same definition, in case you don't know, when a word is used in the dictionary to define another word.

Comment: I suggest you read it, as I have alreaday, and pay attention to the part where it says "**A bucket**".  That's the relevent section.

Comment: "a. An open-topped vessel with a hooped carrying handle, typically of slightly tapering cylindrical shape, used esp. for holding or carrying liquids; (now more generally) **a bucket**."  Notice that there is a semicolon there?  That means that the definition regarding liquid is stopped, and we've moved on to a completly independant, unqualified definition. "**a bucket**".  The semicolon indicates that I'm correct, they mean the same thing.  Further, as google will show you, if you try searching, there are many references to buckets of liquid, like milk.

Comment: milk goes into a bucket. Please see google for usage examples. Bucket has more definitions than pail, that part is true, but, in the context of a comparison of the two words, we're talking about the definition of bucket as it relates to pail, not any additional meanings of the words.  Re read the question.  With that in mind, they are synonymous.  The claim that somehow the two meanings of the words being the same in this case makes them not synonymous isnt logical at all.

Comment: Please see google.  It does.  I've shown you a link, and here again we come to what I've been saying the whole time: You are arguing from personal bias, where you are from they have a distinction, but, the definitions of the word pail and the defnition of the word bucket is the same in this case, and so they are synonymous. Yes, I have spent 3 years on a farm in the Northwest, and we say bucket of milk.  Further, insisting anecdotal stories make you right and not referring to evidence shows you're arguing from personal bias, as I said.

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bucket+of+milk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch I am not arguing from “personal bias”.  I am arguing from ***personal knowledge***.   I am from rural Wisconsin, and believe me, it’s pail there. This fixation with Google is useless and stupid. If I want to do field work in linguistics, I will go around to farmers with a tape recorder. I am a native speaker with personal experience. That is all the citation you need. I do not need to produce tape recordings for you. Ngrams is meaningless for detecting nuance in actual speech. It is not speech. This is like arguing about pop and soda.  It is meaningless and wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's pail there.  I understand that. That's what I've been telling you the entire time.  I am also a native speaker, I have lived on a farm for three years.  Here we say bucket.  Further, I have a degree in writing with a minor in english.  **The idea that your experience is somehow proof is not at all in the spirit of SE**, and that you think it is shows you should re-read the FAQ. Furthermore, again, for the fourth time, I am an english speaking native and here in my area of the united states we do not use the word pail ever.  We always use bucket.  And yes, your argument reflects bias.

Comment: Love the G.R.R. Martin reference, but I'm afraid it's not valid here: since the stories are quasi-medieval, he occasionally uses words in a slightly archaic manner.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Yes, that’s true, and poorly, too.  But the *pail* stuff all made sense to my American ear, and it was sizable text I could grep.

Answer (score 6):

*Pail* is completely synonymous with *bucket*, except in phrases such as *diner pail*, *slop pail*, *oyster pail*, *kick the bucket*, *bucket brigade*, *bucket seat*, *bucket hat*, etc.

Comment: If so, would it be completely natural to use both “this pail of whitewash” and “this bucket of whitewash” interchangeably during the course of the same conversation?

Comment: @Vitaly: yes, I believe it wouldn't feel weird

Comment: I'd have to disagree. Using one or the other would be fine, but switching between words in the middle of a conversation *would* be weird. As @Colin Fine notes in another answer, there appears (anecdotally) to be a UK/US bias too, with the UK favouring bucket and the US using pail more often. I'd recommend picking just one.

Comment: @Dancrumb: In the mid-western US, I think it's perfectly acceptable to use both 'pail' and 'bucket' to refer to the same thing within the same sentence or conversation.  I also wouldn't find it out-of-place to hear one person use 'bucket' and another 'pail' when they're talking about the same object.

Comment: The two words are 100% synonymous, this is wrong.  Anything that you would use pail for can also be called a bucket as their definitions are exactly the same in this context.

Answer (score 6):

In British English, "pail" is very little used, and I would regard it as an archaic synonym of "bucket" in its primary sense.

I have noticed that it appears to be much more common in American English.

Comment: Not in the Northeast part of North America. In fact, had I posted an answer, I might've speculated the geographic opposite.

Comment: @Mark: Yes. That was implicit in my word "archaic".

Comment: +1 for the British usage information, while I am quite versed in american English and speech and idiom, I'm not in UK variants.

Comment: This answer gets a vote from me - I'm English born and in the UK, and we all say bucket - pail is 'old fashioned' but we all know what it means.

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, a bucket was used for things such as feed for animals, whereas a pail was almost always used for liquids and included a spout for easy pouring.

Comment: No citation, and, I've never heard this.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch It’s like the cute little plastic pail a little girl might carry on the beach.  It’s small and has a convenient handle. You really wouldn’t call that a bucket; it wouldn’t sound right. It’s only a pail.

Comment: Yes, I would call it a plastic bucket.  Everyone from my part of the country would as we don't use pail here.  The assertion that it doesnt sound right is an argument from personal bias, and has nothing to do with the real meaning of the word.  Further, he said "Traditionally", which has nothing at all to do with what you just said, so your explanation doesnt even match his answer.

Comment: Do you have evicence for this? From Google books, *Webster's International Dictionary (1892)* says: **pail:** *a vessel for water, milk, etc.* and **bucket:**  *a vessel for drawing and carrying water, etc.* From these definition, I'd say that the thing in the well is always a *bucket*, but that otherwise they're fairly synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

In bulk foods and probably other industries, large pails are used for packaging.  I suppose you can use the word "bucket" to describe these large bulk containers but I think pail, at least in the foods industry, may be the more common word.

Comment: This lacks a citation, I've never heard this, if you'll provide a citation I'll change to an upvote and not a downvote.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch What he says conforms with my use. Apparently you don’t accept the word of a native speaker. How do you think linguistics works???  Here’s another one for you: it’s a garbage pail.  It ***cannot*** be a garbage “bucket”. Similarly, you cannot drop a basketball into its “pail” to score; you must drop it into the bucket.  See the difference now? These are not perfect synonyms, as this proves.

Comment: I am a native speaker, and in my area of the world, we never say pail.  We always say bucket.  I've never heard the word pail used in common speech here.  I am from the Pacific Northwest.  Your assertions are mostly wrong.  Because YOU use them differently in this manner doesnt mean that the dictinary agrees, as it defines PAIL as A BUCKET, as you pointed out.  It also doesn't mean that everyone else uses it the way you do.  Further, and this is neither here nor there, I have a degree in writing and a minor in english, which again is my native language.

Comment: Please stop being insulting by characterizing my speech as "bull". Further, I'll use my vote however I like thank you, as the FAQ says I may.

Answer (score 1):

They're essentially synonyms, but as a Brit, I think *"pail"* is at the very least dated, if not bordering on archaic. I'm quite used to *reading* the word, obviously - but if someone asked me to *"fetch a pail of water"* I'd feel as though I'd slipped back in time to some pre-Victorian nursery rhyme.

Here's the evidence that [Brits haven't favoured the word](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fill%20a%20pail,fill%20a%20bucket&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) for over a century...

[image]

...and here's the evidence that [Americans are coming round](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fill%20a%20pail,fill%20a%20bucket&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) to our way of thinking...

[image]

Comment: I really hate this kind of thing.  It says nothing. Millions of little kids play at the beach with their pails and shovels.  Nobody calls those buckets. Pail is a perfectly normal word. It has its place, and it’s not “archaic”. Please go read the OED entry.

Comment: @tchrist It says "they are essentially synonyms" and goes on to prove his assertion that in British usage pail is archaic.  It answers the question correctly from a British point of view, and as well has the correct American answer in it, they are synonyms. +1

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pail - pail noun 1: a usually cylindrical container with a handle : bucket 1buck·et noun \ˈbə-kət\
1 a typically cylindrical vessel for catching, holding, or carrying liquids or solids - @tchrist yes, in fact they are the same.  Totally. Pail uses BUCKET in it's definition.  Bucket is defined as the same thing that pail is.  You're quite mistaken.  Every dictionary I look at has the same meanings. Every thesaurus I look at has them listed as synonyms.  Every one. You're wrong.;

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch **I stand by the *OED***, which says they are only “near-synonyms” ***NOT SYNONYMS***, and points out several ways that they are not the same.  You are wrong.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/ -
Definition of BUCKET 1  a typically cylindrical vessel for catching, holding, or carrying liquids or solids
PAIL 1: a usually cylindrical container with a handle : bucket
Pail is defined as being a bucket, @tchrist.  In every dictionary I've seen.  Every one.  It's also listed as a synonym in every thesaurus I'vve looked at. The only thing that is NOT synonymous about them is that BUCKET has additional meanings.  That's it. Pail means exactly the same thing as bucket, and bucket in this context means the same thing as pail.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, I have, and the definitions in this context are the same. "nearly", as I said above, in this case only means that a bucket has more definitions than a pail, however in this context, since we're asking about how they relate to each other, they are the same.  Because the word "nearly" is used doesn't imply that somehow the fact that they have the same defintions and are listed as synonyms most places isn't true.  I would say that a little boy was carrying a plastic bucket of water, because it's a bucket.]

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch What part of this don’t you understand: “The precise range of vessels denoted by pail, as distinct from the **near-synonymous** bucket, has varied over time, and ***there continues to be much regional variation.*** As a word for a container for milk **pail has long been preferred** (cf. milk-pail n. at milk n.¹ and adj. Compounds 1b), and it is now frequently taken to be a container for liquids, esp. one made of metal (or plastic); though originally it was made of wooden staves hooped with iron.”

Comment: In your own citation the word bucket is used to define pail.  This means that they can be said to mean the same thing in that context.  The exact same thing, because again, in your citation there is no qualification made, it says, and I quote, **a bucket**.  To imply that somehow the word means something else when the OED defines one as the other makes no sense at all.

Comment: @tchrist You're arguing from personal bias, as you must be from somewhere that makes a distinction between the two. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+bucket+of+milk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 Please see, it's used less commonly, but it's used, as that link shows, quite clearly.

Comment: Because the definition says, with no other qualification at all, "**a bucket**".  I'm not sure why you're not understanding how to interpret the dictionary here, it's pretty clear.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch [Read ’em and weep.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=garbage+pail%2Cgarbage+bucket%2Cpail+of+milk%2Cbucket+of+milk&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this is a poor use of ngrams, because the context is not given. Without context, you cannot tell which is being used, so become meaningless. Please see my own answer for an ngram specifically showing more surrounding context, and the large difference in frequency between the two pairs of uses in those contexts.

Comment: @tchrist: I have no idea why three people downvoted my answer, but given that I specifically answered **as a Brit**, I stand by it. Your Ngram effectively just reflects US usage. And none too well at that - Brits certainly never refer to, for example *"garbage pails"*. The US/UK corpus frequency values from your NGram imply Brits use *"garbage pail"* about 1/2 as often as Americans, but in truth I doubt it's even 1/20th as often. NGrams US/UK classification isn't particularly reliable, but there is a real difference in our usage of *pail*, as per my answer.

Comment: Me, I wanna know what the run on *lunch pails* around 1958 was all about. :)

Comment: @tchrist: Presumably *lunch pail/bucket* sound fairly normal to you, but as a Brit I have to say neither container is appropriate for human food - we'd only expect to find pigswill in either. Or Kentucky Fried Chicken, which is generally reckoned to be the iconic "junk fast food" in the UK. KFC's "bargain bucket" is particularly disparaged over here (for the supposedly poor nutritional value of the contents, as much as for the off-putting terminology itself). We don't have any other "food" in buckets or pails - we just use *lunch **boxes***.

Comment: Yes, a slops pail is certainly an unappealing notion. Lunch box doesn’t sound wrong to me, but lunch bucket does. The reason a child at the beach would only have a pail and shovel and not a bucket and shovel is because of some vague notion that the bucket would be too big and heavy for a little child to carry, but the pail wouldn’t.  As the OED suggests, these things are hard to pin down, considering how much the connotations vary with time and place.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, like I say, Brits rarely use the word "pail" at all these days. We're perfectly familiar with it, obviously, since we all know [Jack and Jill went up the hill \ To fetch a pail of water.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_Jill_(nursery_rhyme)). But I think the point made in your answer about *pails* tending to hold liquid works for us too. Plus, *pails* are "cleaner", so to the extent that they still exist today, we'd rather read about *milk pails* than *milk buckets*.

Comment: @tchrist: I can only hope that your recent "tickling" of this question will prompt a few Brits to counteract the (imho ridiculous) downvotes on my answer. I don't doubt that to many Americans (and many dictionaries) there are significant semantic differences between *bucket* and *pail*. But to most ordinary British speakers, I'm sure the only significant difference is that nobody uses the word *pail* any more.

Answer (score 0):

A cooper at Black Creek Pioneer Village in Toronto said that a pail had a smaller bottom than its open top, and that a bucket had a larger bottom than its open top. Thus a bucket was more stable, and were preferred on sailing ships which pitched and rolled. As well, with a smaller opening, there was less chance of the contents splashing out.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I don't suppose you have a more authoritative source than a cooper? This seems like a plausible distinction between the two words but it would help if there some dictionary support.